# How to modify a multi-level menu to work with *ngFor & querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been stuck on this forever, and I cannot figure out the issue. I think I may just be out of luck as querySelectorAll isn't very ... angular.

I have implemented the multi-level-menu into an application from this codrops: tympanus.net/codrops/2015/11/17/multi-level-menu/

It works great. Perfectly.

EXCEPT, when I use *ngFor to create the menus and sub menus.

```
  <section class="list">
          <nav id="ml-menu" class="menu">
            <button class="action action--close" aria-label="Close Menu"><span class="icon icon--cross"></span></button>
            <div class="menu__wrap">

              <ul data-menu="main" class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item" *ngFor='let a of data'><a class="menu__link" attr.data-submenu="{{a.name}}">{{a.name}}</a></li>
              </ul>

              <ul attr.data-menu="{{a.name}}" *ngFor='let a of data' class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item" *ngFor="let b of a.subdata"><a class="menu__link">{{b.name}}</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </section>
```

The point of contention is this line of javascript, using queryselectorall to get the menu levels:

```
 this.menus = [].slice.call(this.el.querySelectorAll('.menu__level'));
```

When I hand code the html menus, I get this as the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiMAb.jpg

When I use *ngFor I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlLli.jpg

Can anyone help me figure out why? I'm running the build menu command in **ngAfterViewInit** as well.

Data is in the following format (it gets mapped in the component service):

```
0 : name: "Name1"
    subdata: Array(3)
    0:{name: "Apple", score: true, id: "pi-cc"}
    1:{name: "Banana", score: true, id: "pi-01"}
    2:{name: "Orange", score: true, id: "pi-02"}
1 : name: "Name2"
    subdata: Array(3)
    0:{name: "Red", score: true, id: "pj-cc"}
    1:{name: "Blue", score: true, id: "pj-01"}
    2:{name: "Green", score: true, id: "pj-02"}
```

etc.

Comment: Would help to see more of the component. What is 'data'?

Comment: Given that the `menu__level` elements are created dynamically, my guess is that they do not yet exist when you query for them. Or that `this.el` doesn't point to what you think it does -- remember angular does view encapsulation unless you explicitly disable it.

Comment: Added data so it is a little clearer for you. 

I agree that they might not exist, yet, but 
`el = document.getElementById('ml-menu');`

This returns the same object with all of the complete options -- as far as I can tell. It returns 

`<nav _ngcontent-c17="" class="menu" id="ml-menu">`

Which is expandable like the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're accessing the DOM before that Angular can inject the elements.

If you want an advice, avoid direct access to the DOM as much as possible, it's not only wrong for portability but it also dangerous and it brings a lot of troubles.

A better (more efficient, more elegant, more *Angular*) way to accomplish it, is using the *ViewChildren* decorator. Firstly, you have to reference your template elements with a variable:

```
 <ul 
    #level 
    attr.data-menu="{{a.name}}" 
    *ngFor='let a of data' 
    class="menu__level">
      <li 
         class="menu__item" 
         *ngFor="let b of a.subdata"><a class="menu__link">
            {{b.name}}
       </li>
 </ul>
```

Then you have to require the reference in the component:

```
@ViewChildren('level', {read: ElementRef}) levels: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Then you can use the variable to get the template of any level:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  let firstLevel = this.levels._results[0].nativeElement;
}
```

Or convert your *QueryList* into an *Array* (how you tried in your question):

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.menus = this.levels
                 .toArray()
                 .map(el => el.nativeElement);
}
```